# Haskell equivalent of Ruby's slice_when

Tags: haskell, slice

I am new to Haskell, and I want a function works like Ruby's slice_when:

[slice_when](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when)
**Ruby**

```
a = [1,2,4,9,10,11,12,15,16,19,20,21]
b = a.slice_when {|i, j| i+1 != j }
p b.to_a #=> [[1, 2], [4], [9, 10, 11, 12], [15, 16], [19, 20, 21]]
```

**Haskell**

```
ghci > slice_when (\x y -> x+1 /= y) [1,2,4,9,10,11,12,15,16,19,20,21] 

=> [[1, 2], [4], [9, 10, 11, 12], [15, 16], [19, 20, 21]]
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: As far as prelude functions, there's [`break`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:break), which does it once.  It's not too hard to use break recursively to get `slice_when`'s behavior, but there's no prelude function that does it.  Surely the [`split`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.1/docs/Data-List-Split.html) package has what you need.

Comment: Oops, I see, `slice_when` works on pairs.  This will be a bit more involved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here’s a `sliceWhen` implementation that I believe works like you want:

```
sliceWhen :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
sliceWhen _ []  = []
sliceWhen _ [x] = [[x]]
sliceWhen f (x:y:xs)
  | f x y     = [x] : sliceWhen f (y:xs)
  | otherwise = let z:zs = sliceWhen f (y:xs)
                in (x:z) : zs
```

The above function runs the provided predicate on each boundary, and if it returns `True`, it creates a seam. Otherwise, it tacks the “current” value onto the first element of the rest of the list.

Comment: This works very well, thank you for your answer. ^.^

Answer (score 3):

Without explicit recursion, and using [`NonEmpty`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html):

```
import Data.List.NonEmpty

sliceWhen :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [NonEmpty a]
sliceWhen p = foldr f []
    where
    f z [] = [z :| []]
    f z gss@(gs@(x :| xs) : xss) = if p z x
                                   then (z :| []) : gss
                                   else cons z gs : xss
```

Comment: Hi, I run and got [1 :| [2],4 :| [],9 :| [10,11,12],15 :| [16],19 :| [20,21]], seems ok, but I can't understand this result, can you tell me, how can I transform it to [[1,2],[4],[9,10,11,12],[15,16],[19,20,21]], I am a novice, many thanks.

Comment: It looks weird because the inner NonEmpty values are shown as pair of a first element and a list, like `9 :| [10,11,12]`. You can convert the inner values to regular lists using `map`, like this: `Prelude.map toList $ sliceWhen (\x y -> x+1 /= y) [1,2,4,9,10,11,12,15,16,19,20,21]`.